# TYPO3 fluid translate view helper: No output when using "%0A%0A" in xlf file

Tags: typo3, fluid

In my fluid Template I am using

`{f:translate(key:'LLL:path/to/file/locallang.xlf:Test', arguments: {0: 'Test'})}`

## Positive test case

Content of locallang.xlf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff version="1.0">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2016-12-06T14:00:00Z" product-name="">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="Test" xml:space="preserve">
                <source><![CDATA[mailto:info@example.org?Subject=%1$s&Body=Hello%0A]]></source>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Output:

```
mailto:info@example.org?Subject=Test&Body=Hello
```

## Negative test case

Content of locallang.xlf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff version="1.0">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2016-12-06T14:00:00Z" product-name="">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="Test" xml:space="preserve">
                <source><![CDATA[mailto:info@example.org?Subject=%1$s&Body=Hello%0A%0A]]></source>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Output is an empty string

What is causing the empty output instead of the expected, encoded double line break?

I just found the underlaying PHP error message:

```
#1: PHP Warning: vsprintf(): Too few arguments in LocalizationUtility.php line 115
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character '%' should be escaped as '%%' as described in the [PHP documentation for sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

This leads to

```
 <source><![CDATA[mailto:info@example.org?Subject=%1$s&Body=Hello%%0A%%0A]]></source>
```

instead of

```
 <source><![CDATA[mailto:info@example.org?Subject=%1$s&Body=Hello%0A%0A]]></source>
```